# Test different calendars on iOS

Tags: ios, testing, calendar, nscalendar

I have an app that relies heavily on date calculations. I am using NSCalendar and doing all the calculations "the right way", but I don't really have any way to test any other calendar besides the default US one.

How can you change the calendar used on iOS? Where can I find more information about calendar alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change it on your Device/Simulator. Open Settings -> General -> International. Here you can change the format of the calendar date or the calendar itself.